Faulty VL805/806 xHCI USB 3.0 Controller since kernel upgrade
I have PCI-E USB extension cards which are not working properly after a kernel update: USB devices are detected but dropped immediately. This means I cannot use, for example, my wireless headphone's USB stick in that extension card only in a USB slot of the motherboard.
I experience the issue since linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic kernel package was installed in my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS then also in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with 6.8.0-44-generic.
Any idea how to fix it?
5:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805/806 xHCI USB 3.0 Controller (rev 01)

dmesg:
[   68.549318] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command
[   68.613928] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: Host halt failed, -110
[   68.613931] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[   68.613943] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: HC died; cleaning up


Solution: turn off intel iommu in /etc/default/grub file.
/etc/default/grub:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_iommu=off"

For your reference if you are facing same issue:

My CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700K CPU @ 3.60GHz
My baseboard: Gigabyte B365 HD3
OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

